# JavaFX Markdown Renderer

Tags: open-source, library, java, markdown

Are there any libraries that will render markdown (ideally by the CommonMark specification) in JavaFX? The library should allow me to embed a pane with JavaFX pane inside a stage and pass it markdown text which it will display as formatted, rich text.

I have found [MarkdownWriterFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX), but it is not a library, and requires significant reverse-engineering in order to use in a context other than its own. I would like something easier to use.

The library must be open-source and free to use. Ideally it should be in a public maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying [markdown-javafx-renderer](https://github.com/JPro-one/markdown-javafx-renderer)? It is based on [flexmark-java](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java).

Example application: https://github.com/jpro-one/markdown-javafx-renderer/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/sandec/mdfx/ExampleMDFX.java

Usage:

```
import com.sandec.mdfx.MDFXNode;

MDFXNode mdfx = new MDFXNode("your-markdown");
content.getStylesheets().add("/com/sandec/mdfx/mdfx-default.css");
```